# Expression must have a class type (Beginner error in C++ Windows 8 App using Win2D)

Tags: c++-cli, drawing, win2d

I am trying to get started using Win2D inside a Windows 8 application.  I have merely attempted to install the library to my new project and draw a circle using one of the functions, but can go no further due to an error I don't understand.

Shown below is the event handler created automatically inside the Mainpage.xaml.cpp file.  My error is that the'args'part at the beginning of the single line of code inside the function is underlined in red. Hovering over the red line under 'args' shows the message "expression must have class type".  Can anyone help with this?

```
void AdditiveSignals::MainPage::CanvasAnimatedControl_Draw(Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::UI::Xaml::ICanvasAnimatedControl^ sender, Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::UI::Xaml::CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs^ args)
{
    args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(640, 360, 30.0f, Colors->Blue);
}
```

---

Here is the full code if required

In MainPage.xaml.h

```
//
// MainPage.xaml.h
// Declaration of the MainPage class.
//

#pragma once

#include "MainPage.g.h"

namespace AdditiveSignals
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MainPage sealed
    {
    public:
        MainPage();

    protected:
        virtual void OnNavigatedTo(Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationEventArgs^ e) override;
    private:
        void CanvasAnimatedControl_Draw(Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::UI::Xaml::ICanvasAnimatedControl^ sender, Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::UI::Xaml::CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs^ args);
    };
}
```

In MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="AdditiveSignals.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AdditiveSignals"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:canvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <canvas:CanvasAnimatedControl Draw="CanvasAnimatedControl_Draw" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cpp (full code)

```
//
// MainPage.xaml.cpp
// Implementation of the MainPage class.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"

using namespace AdditiveSignals;

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

/// <summary>
/// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
/// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
void MainPage::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
    (void) e;   // Unused parameter

    // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

    // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
    // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
    // Windows::Phone::UI::Input::HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
    // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
    // this event is handled for you.
}

//This event handler will be called 60 times per second
void AdditiveSignals::MainPage::CanvasAnimatedControl_Draw(Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::UI::Xaml::ICanvasAnimatedControl^ sender, Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::UI::Xaml::CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs^ args)
{


    args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(640, 360, 30.0f, Colors->Blue);
}
```

Comment: I think this should be under the C++/CLI tag, as this is C++/CLI source. [read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard note about the language: C++/CLI is intended as a bridge to allow C# or other .Net code to call C++ code. It is not intended as a primary development language. If you want to learn C++, I would use C++ with MFC as your GUI toolkit. If you want to learn managed code, I'd learn C# with either WinForms or WPF.

That said:

```
void CanvasAnimatedControl_Draw(ICanvasAnimatedControl^ sender, CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs^ args)
{
    args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(640, 360, 30.0f, Colors->Blue);
}
```

`args` is a reference type, not a value type. (It was passed to you by reference (`^`), which is roughly analogous to passing a C++ object by pointer (`*`).) Since it's a reference type, its members are accessed using `->`, rather than `.`, just like a C++ pointer to an object.

`DrawingSession` is also a reference type, so its members are also accessed using `->`.

`Colors` is the name of a class; static members are accessed using `::`.

```
args->DrawingSession->DrawCircle(640, 360, 30.0f, Colors::Blue);
```